# Are personal experience questions (How is it to work in a lab) appropriate?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm at a crossroads in my career, and am interested in **what the modern science is like for a person who's working in a lab**. How is it to be a scientist: neurobiologist, neuroscientist, or work with other areas of life sciences?

Are such questions appropriate for this website, or are there better, more appropriate places, like blogs, etc where such answers can be found?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to say that such questions are too subjective for a Stack Exchange site and are likely to receive close votes as *not constructive*:

> As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. If you feel that this question can be improved and possibly reopened, see the FAQ for guidance.

Comment: Yes, I would say that in a question like the OP asks, all answers would be valid. That said, there are certainly blogs and other spaces where such questions would better fit. :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that questions of these nature are not a good fit for Biology.SE, however you may try asking them over in Academia.SE because it would certainly fit in that forum.

Comment: But, not all scientist work in academia. A few of us have gone over to the dark side of industry :)

Comment: Haha, well there is no equivalent forum for you dark-side scientists. Have you tried the Death Star yet?

Comment: we're having stability problems, so I'm telecommuting for now...

Comment: I guess some of dark industry questions can be asked there (I'm active there and I will defend :)), as long as there are somewhat related to academic world, or to research issues (otherwise there is http://workplace.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is dark industry?